# программное удаление элемента по названию класса

Tags: java, android

Не получается удалить программно элементы, соответствующие определенному классу (TextView). Удаляет все элементы. Подскажите. Спасибо.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/activity_main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <Button
  android:text="create"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

 <Button
  android:text="remove all"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
  android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>

 <android.support.constraint.Guideline
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/guideline1"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.12"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
 private ConstraintSet constraintSet;

 private Button button1;
 private Button button2;
 private android.support.constraint.Guideline guideline1;
 private int counter;

 //method convert dp to pixels
 private int funConvertDpToPixel(float dp) {
  return (int)(dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
 }

 //method create element
 private TextView funCreate() {
  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  counter++;
  textView.setId(counter);
  textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
  textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
  textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
  textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
  textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c2185b"));
  return textView;
 }

 //method add element in layout
 @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
 private void funAdd(TextView textView) {
  //добавление элемента управления в ConstraintLayout
  constraintLayout.addView(textView);

  //программно настраиваем ConstraintLayout (это делает класс ConstraintSet)
  constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

  //ширина элемента
  constraintSet.constrainWidth(textView.getId(), funConvertDpToPixel(50));
  //высота элемента
  constraintSet.constrainHeight(textView.getId(), funConvertDpToPixel(50));

  //привязка
  if(textView.getId() == 1) {
   constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, guideline1.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
   constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
   constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
  } else {
   constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, textView.getId() - 1, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, funConvertDpToPixel(15));
   constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
   constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
  }

  //применение настроек к текущему ConstraintLayout
  constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
 }

 //method remove elements
 private void funRemove() {
  //обход всех элементов
  for(int i=0; i<constraintLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
   //соответствие элемента классу TextView
   if(constraintLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) {
    //удаление элемента
    constraintLayout.removeViewAt(i);
   }
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
  button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
  guideline1 = findViewById(R.id.guideline1);

  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    funAdd(funCreate());
   }
  });

  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    funRemove();
   }
  });

 }
}
```

Comment: Вы добавляете в разметку TextView через код или они в xml уже определены ?

Comment: Уважаемый KolinLoures, я добавляю TextView через код.

Comment: А остальные элементы не наследники `TextView` ака `EditText`, `Button` ...?

Comment: Уважаемый woesss, я изменил вопрос и вставил полный код. Остальные элементы не наследники.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что удаляются все элементы, так как **Button** является прямым наследником **TextView**.

Условие:

```
constraintLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView
```

не только для кнопки будет **true**, но и для **CheckBox**, **EditText**.

Comment: Уважаемый KolinLoures, спасибо Вам! Как можно решить эту проблему наследования?

Comment: @Anton, `if (constraintLayout.getChildAt(i).getClass() == TextView.class)` - так попробуйте. Или то же, но сравнить через `quals()`

Comment: Еще вариант задавать setTag() для TextView и прихранивать все tag в коллекции или в массиве. Потом когда необходимо все TextView удалить, можно просто пройтись по массиву тегов и вызвать:

                    constraintLayout.removeView(constraintLayout.findViewWithTag(tag))

Comment: @Anton Решение woesss более простое и быстрое, так что можешь выбрать какое тебе подходит больше

Comment: Уважаемый woesss! Спасибо Вам! Все получилось. Только остается один textview. После второго нажатия на кнопку удаляется и он.

Comment: @Anton замените ConstraintLayout  на LinearLayout, тогда все нормально должно удаляться